# Pass explict empty arguments pack

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, variadic-templates

I'm trying to overload constructors as follows

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int, int);

    template<typename... Args>
    foo(int, int, Args... args);
}
```

`foo(int, int)` behaves differently from `foo(int, int, empty_arguments_pack)`. 
I want `foo(1, 2)` to call `foo(int, int)` and something like `foo(1, 2,   )` to call `foo(int, int, Args...)`. How can i do that?

Comment: That seems wrong, why would you want that? `foo<>(1,2)` will do what you want.

Comment: @Quimby We can't do that for constructors.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yea, I discovered it now while trying to make an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call explicitly template constructor as `foo<>(1, 2) /*Illegal*/`

You might create other tagged overloads `foo(special_tag, int, int/*, Args...*/)` to solve your issue

```cpp
struct special_tag{};

class foo
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    foo(special_tag, int i1, int i2, Args... args) { /**/}

    foo(int, int) { /*...*/}

    // And possibly
    template<typename... Args>
    foo(int i1, int i2, Args... args) : foo(special_tag{}, i1, i2, args...) { /*...*/}
};
```

Now, you can use:

```cpp
foo(1, 2); // foo(int, int)
foo(special_tag{}, 1, 2); // foo(special_tag, int, int, Args...)
foo(special_tag{}, 1, 2, 3); // foo(special_tag, int, int, Args...)
// And possibly:
foo(1, 2, 3); // foo(int, int, Args...) so foo(special_tag, int, int, Args...)
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how special_tag would solve my problem, can you explain me how it works

Comment: Oh, I understand something a little different before your edit. Answer fixed.

Comment: A bit ugly but it is the only way to solve my problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you would like `foo(1, 2)` to call the variadic template constructor, what will you write when you want to call `foo(int, int)`?

My suggestion is:

1. Declare a nested class;
2. Specify the template constructor;
3. Append an object of the nested class after two `int`s if you want to call the variadic template constructor.

Your code should look like:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    class Special {};

    Foo(int, int) { /* ... */ }

    template <typename... Args>
    Foo(int, int, Args&&...) { /* ... */ }

    template <typename... Args>
    Foo(int, int, Special, Args&&...) { /* ... */ }
};
```